# @Ajax.BeginForm и unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, валидация

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с валидацией формы. Есть частичное представление, в котором:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Task", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "content",
}))
{
<input id="datepicker" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо выбрать дату окончания задания" data-val-date="введите корректную дату">                
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="endDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ok</button>
}
```

И 2 варианта развития событий. Если скрипты подключены только на Layout, то валидация не работает. Если подключить скрипты в этом же представлении всей кучей:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

То валидация работает, однако Action будет срабатывать 2 раза. В чем проблема и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если скрипты подключены только на Layout'е, то формы в `html`-разметке, полученной динамически (с помощью Ajax-запросов, например, как в вашем случае) не будут валидироваться. Так происходит, потому что клиентский валидатор абсолютно ничего не знает о появившихся на странице формах. Он парсит страницу на предемет форм один раз - после её загрузки. В этом можно легко убедиться, открыв файл `"jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"` и посмотрев в конец:

```
$(function () {
    $jQval.unobtrusive.parse(document);
});
```

Поэтому, в вашем PartialView нужно явно заставить валидатор обрабатывать новую форму:

```
<script>
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#form_id'); // 'form_id' - id новой формы
</script>
```

В случае, когда вы подключаете скрипты валидации в PartialView, валидация будет работать, по озвученной выше причине. Но submit формы будет срабатывать 2 раза, потому что обработчик события будет срабатывать 2 раза - в каждом из подключенных скриптов `"jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нашел еще вариант решения с вызовом валидации по OnSuccess = "onSuccess", если Ajax идет несколько друг за другом. Сейчас оба попробую.